# What is required datasource for Kendo Scheduler and what is the "from" for?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I am confused about wiring up my own datasource to the Kendo Scheduler. I looked at their API and I'm still confused. For instance, I see it says the start and the end are required, but are they the names of the fields in my dataset? They can't be mapped to another name?

My dataset has some other details as well as a date in the format, "2016-10-20T00:00:00." Is this going to work?

Can someone tell me if the actual field names from the DB/JSON are literally the same as in Telerik's docs? For instance, my date field isn't called "Start" and End. It's something else, and I don't even have an end, and I don't have starttimezone and endtimezone, are these all needed?

**Another question I have is**: I'm not limited to just the fields from their documentation am I? I have a datasource that has other things, for instance, we don't have "title," we have something else. And riding off that question, I'm hoping that when I call the pop up when the user double clicks on a time/day or event, that I can customize what fields I want to appear.

The other question is: **What is the "from" attribute/property for?** For instance

end: { type: "date", from: "End" },

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My two cents on this:

I think the options "Title", "Start" and "End" are the ones that are always needed on the dataSource. "startTimezone" and "endTimezone" are not always needed.

I also think that the "from" attribute/property is a reference to from where you are getting that data. I mean, which field from the database guards a specific information.

You can also have your own custom fields to the model, as long as they came from a valid field from the database and as long as they have an correspondent and valid datatype value.

At last but not the least, you can also customize what fields you can make appear once you do double-click and the pop-up window shows up. For that, you must use your own template for a [custom](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/scheduler/how-to/custom-edit-and-event-templates) pop-up editor.

Hope this gives you some insight.

Comment: Thanks for your post. I'll try this out soon and give feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So far I'm having ill luck. My issue now is, I'm receiving the error, "Cannot read property 'getTimezoneOffset' of null." Does anyone know why this would appear?

Comment: In the past, I had a little problem like that. However, I don't remember exactly how did I solved that issue. I messed around with the code for weeks and I managed to solve something. Kendo Scheduler topic on StackOverflow isn't very followed by other users. Anyway, here's again my two cents: make sure datatime types are the same on the database and on the schema. Also, another aproach I can think of are in relation to comment timezone property. At last but not the least, in my case, I remembered that I had to make sure with a function that the data was converted to JSONdate.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I figured out the core issue with the error. It was a matter of me tweaking my schema model.